# How to restore deleted pages/posts?

Tags: get-posts, customization

I recently deleted some pages in my wordpress site. Now I want to re-store them. How can I do this?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just "moved to trash" or "deleted permanently"?

Comment: I just moved trash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Then you should see a link "Trash" on the top of pages/posts listing section.

- Click on that link which will take you the section where all the trashed pages/posts are listed.
- Select the pages/posts using the checkboxes against them.
- Select `Restore` from `Bulk Actions` dropdown, then hit the `Apply` button.
- Now go to pages/posts listing section and you should see the trashed pages/posts published again.

Comment: I could not see the Trash link refresh the page as it did not show up for me at first but I had to refresh the Pages page and then Trash (1) was visible.

Answer (score 4):

Since you only moved them to trash, you can easily restore them

When you are on the posts or pages page in the admin area, click on the trash link at the top of the screen. Now you will see your posts or pages that you moved to trash, just hover over one of them and click on "restore"

You can also use the checkboxes to select multiple at once, and from the dropdown menu that says "bulk actions", select restore to place them all back